# 編集の差分表示が分かりにくい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 使い勝手, 差分表示

差分の表示があまりにも分かりにくい、見づらいので改善して欲しいです。
差分ロジックもあまり賢くないのか、文の途中の文字を使ってしまうので、どう変更されたかが差分表示ではわかりづらいです。

**例：**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
こんな表示では暗号を見ているようです･･･

Comment: diffできるソフト等を知ってたら検討ができますが、現在日本人の開発者がいないため、自分で開発しても適切になる可能性が低いです。

Comment: @jmac `jsdifflib`はどうですか？

Comment: 開発者に聞いてみますが、`jsdifflib`は２行でしか出力しないみたいです。現在タイトルは一行でdiffを見せています。日本語で一行で差を見せるのは普段ないでしょうか？

Comment: @jmac すみませんよく確認せずに提案しました･･･(インラインだと思い込みました)。一行での差分表示は一般的だと思います。もう少しインライン表示ができそうなものを探してみますが、現在使用している差分ロジックの開示は難しいのでしょうか(もしくは何らかのライブラリを使用している？)。GitHubあたりに公開して日本語対応版を開発するのも良いと思います。

Comment: 実際の表示の確認用にリンクを貼ります: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/5112/revisions / ネットワーク全体のメタでは[別の行に分けて表示するという案](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135710/157841)が出ていました。

Comment: 現在開発者は[TinySegementer](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/TinySegmenter/)のようなライブラリを検討しています。

Comment: @jmac なるほど。日本語の文字列のかたまり毎でdiffを取る感じですね。ひとまず良さそうです。entoさんが教えて下さった案の良いですし、本文と同じようにタイトルも左右のdiff表示となっても良い気がしますね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

編集の`diff`を本文でも、タイトルでも[TinySegementer](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/TinySegmenter/)の[C# port](http://wiki.dobon.net/index.php?free%2FTinySegmenter.NET)を利用した上で`diff`を適用するつもりです。現在は一文字毎で行っているので、適用後より読みやすくなるはずです。

Comment: とても読みやすくなりました。対応ありがとうございます！